# Vector equations, solve for what and how to

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I got this question as a task for second grade high school math, and I can't really figure out what to solve for and how to solve it.

$$2(k\vec a+\vec x)+m\vec x=5\vec a-k\vec x-m\vec a$$

I think this should be an easy question, as we just started working with vectors and this was at the start of the test.

I've tried isolating $x$ and $a$, I got

$\vec a(5-m-2k)$ and

$\vec{x}(k+2+m)$

but this didn't get me any further. I don't know what i'm supposed to solve for / find when solving, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Isolate $\vec{x}$ on one side.

Comment: @Shahab I did that, got `x(k+2+m)`

Comment: $k+2+m$ is a number. If it is not zero, what can you do with it to get $x$?

Comment: @VedranŠego typoed in question, look now

Comment: My previous comment, as well as the one under amWhy's answer, still stands. Don't be confused by the fact that $x$ is a vector. It is perfectly normal for it to be a solution of this vector equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about gathering like terms (like vectors), with the objective of isolating one of the variables (a vector) to express it as a function of the other variable (a vector):

$$\begin{align}2(k\vec a + \vec x) +m\vec x = 5\vec a - k\vec x -m\vec a & \iff 2k\vec a + 2\vec x+m\vec x = 5\vec a - k\vec x -m\vec a\\ \\ & \iff  2k\vec a - 5 \vec a + m \vec a   = -k\vec x - m\vec x \\ \\ & \iff (2k - 5+ m)\vec a = -(k + 2 + m)\vec x\\ \\ & \;\;\;\text{or}\quad(k + 2 + m)\vec x = (5 - 2k - m)\vec a\end{align}$$

Now you can express $\vec x$ as a function of $\vec a$, or vice versa, dividing by the respective parenthetical coefficient, provided $k + 2 + m \neq 0$ when solving for $\vec x$, or provided $(5 - 2k - m)\neq 0$ in the case of solving for $\vec a$.

Comment: I came as far as that aswell, but isn't the goal of this to find the values of M and K?

Comment: @OscarApeland It is more likely you need to find $x$ (in dependence of $a$).

Comment: Oscar: there is not enough information to solve for $m, k$. Typically, the variables in a vector equation are the vectors. We treat unknown coefficients merely as coefficients. The objective is usually to isolate one of the vectors: for example, we can write $$\vec x = \left(\dfrac{5-2k - m}{k + 2+m}\right) \vec a,\quad k + 2 + m \neq 0$$ Thus having solved for $\vec x$ as a function of $\vec a$.

Comment: @amWay For the sake of completeness, if $k+2+m=0$, then the solution is either any $x$ (if $5-2k-m=0$ or $a=0$) or such $x$ doesn't exist.

Comment: amWhy and vedran, thanks. I'll write Lisa and your answer for the hand-in, and say that I didn't fully understand the question.

Comment: @amWhy: Nicely illustrated and discussion +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that, as when working with scalars, you just perform the same operations on each side of the equality. This means that what you have done so far can be expressed like this:

$$ \vec{x}(k+2+m)=\vec{a}(5-m-2k) $$

This should make it easier to identify the next step necessary to isolate $x$.

Comment: I think that my goal is to find out what M and K is, not to isolate X. X and A are vectors

Comment: do you know what $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{a}$ are? Can you give us the exact problem definition?

Comment: You shouldn't have to "guess" what they are looking for - I'm sure they stated exactly what the goal is, otherwise it would be an ill-posed problem.

Comment: The question was: "Solve this vector equation:" and then the equation in my question.

Comment: Ok. That's not a very clear problem then.. But traditionally, $\vec{x}$ is what you have to solve for.

Comment: Yeah, thats why i'm so confused, it seemed a bit above my level and it was very unclear.